# How to disassemble .NET after using Confuser

Tags: debugging, tools, .net

I want to test malware that wrote in .NET 4.5 and obfuscated by Confuser 1.9.

I have tried to open it with .NET Reflector, ILSpy and dotpeek, but all of them can't open it.

How can I debug (and modify) it? There is a special tool for that?

Comment: The whole point of obfuscators is to make decompilation harder. Have you tried ildasm?

Comment: @svick, yes it failed to.. Only IDA Pro succeeded to show me the MSIL but it can't debug or modify it.

Comment: There is a project https://github.com/UbbeLoL/ConfuserDeobfuscator . I didn;t use it personally, but it worth a try.

Comment: @ws when I try to load the project it crashed :P...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try http://de4dot.com its a powerful .net deobfuscator. I've authored a serie of tutorials dubbed "demystifying dot net reverse engineering" google it, its a great point of start if you are new on .net RE.

Here is an article on how to deal with obfuscated assemblies http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/reverse-engineering-obfuscated-assemblies/

And this is directly related to what you asked for : [.NET] Decrypt Confuser 1.9 methods : http://fr.scribd.com/doc/207710371/NET-Decrypt-Confuser-1-9-Methods#scribd

Good luck

Comment: de4dot does not list Confuser under Supported Obfuscators:
https://github.com/de4dot/de4dot